# google direction service returns different waypoints

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am using the Direction Service API with a list of via waypoints which returns a distance of 5.9Km.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.463368,1.568641&destination=43.459847,1.572251&waypoints=via:43.463073,1.569196|via:43.462763,1.569736|via:43.462436,1.570256|via:43.462077,1.570725|via:43.46163,1.571009|via:43.461188,1.57133|via:43.460735,1.57162|via:43.460289,1.571931&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&departure_time=now

I am checking the same journey with the same waypoints in google maps which returns a distance of 0.5Km as expected.
https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/'43.463368,1.568641'/'43.463073,1.569196'/'43.462763,1.569736'/'43.462436,1.570256'/'43.462077,1.570725'/'43.46163,1.571009'/'43.461188,1.57133'/'43.460735,1.57162'/'43.460289,1.571931'/'43.459847,1.572251'

Has anyone encountered such a problem? Can anyone explain why I'm seeing such a difference?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `via:` prefix (no stopover), it adds some additional restrictions. Particularly the U-turn maneuver is not allowed, the route must go straight forward through waypoint.

The official documentation states the following:

> **Caution:** Using the via: prefix to avoid stopovers results in directions that are very strict in their interpretation of the waypoint. This may result in severe detours on the route or ZERO_RESULTS in the response status code if the Google Maps Directions API is unable to create directions through that point.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

Now let's have a look at you example in Directions calculator

https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=43.463368%2C1.568641&destination=43.459847%2C1.572251&mode=driving&waypoints=via:43.463073%2C1.569196%7Cvia:43.462763%2C1.569736%7Cvia:43.462436%2C1.570256%7Cvia:43.462077%2C1.570725%7Cvia:43.46163%2C1.571009%7Cvia:43.461188%2C1.57133%7Cvia:43.460735%2C1.57162%7Cvia:43.460289%2C1.571931

As you can see the waypoints 5 and 6 will require a kind of U-Turn that is not allowed for `via:` prefix and leads to serious detour

[image]

Now compare it to the route without `via:` prefix

https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=43.463368%2C1.568641&destination=43.459847%2C1.572251&mode=driving&waypoints=43.463073%2C1.569196%7C43.462763%2C1.569736%7C43.462436%2C1.570256%7C43.462077%2C1.570725%7C43.46163%2C1.571009%7C43.461188%2C1.57133%7C43.460735%2C1.57162%7C43.460289%2C1.571931

I hope this addresses your question!